# Iterate through keys found in collection

Tags: mongodb, iteration

I have a collection called `integers` (names are changed for the purpose of example) from which I retrieve one document with `UUID: 1` using `findOne()`. Then, I'm going deeper by going into `intObject.intVal` which returns me a "collection" of values storing ararys like below:

```
var intObject = db.integers.findOne(
    { "UUID": 1, "intVal": { $exists: true } },
    { "_id": false, "intVal": true }
  );

intObjectWithin = intObject.intVal;
```

Response from server:

```
{
   "retval": {
     "KEY1": [
       3,
       5 
    ],
     "KEY2": [
       4 
    ],
     "KEY3": [
       2,
       5,
       3,
       5 
    ] 
  },
   "ok": 1 
}
```

I need to be able to loop through those keys and calculate an average value for each key in this returned document.

**I'm struggling with the "loop through keys" for a document.** I've been trying to call `forEach()` and iterate but can't find the proper way to access all keys and iterate through their values separately.

I've successfully written a function to calculate average value given `UUID, keyName` pair and accessed it's values by `intObject.intVal[keyName]` but don't know how to do it "for each key found within". When I have that I will be able to nest already written function to perform what I need to achieve.

Could you please provide me with the right way?

---

**UPDATE:**

If my explanation is a bit clumsy then an example should help understand it:
for the response (mentioned above) I would need to iterate through `KEY1`, `KEY2` and `KEY3` not knowing its' actual names (thus the ambiguous names) and perform some action for each document which would look like:

- First loop: `[3,5]`
- Second loop: `[4]`
- Third loop: `[2,5,3,5]`

Comment: Something like `Object.keys(intObjectWithin).forEach(key => { intObjectWithin[key].forEach(val => console.log(val)) });` should output all values across all keys.